# postgres group by aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a messages table which looks like this:

```
+------------+-------------+----------+
| sender_id  |  created_at | message  |
+------------+-------------+----------+
|      1     | 2010-06-14  | the msg  |
|      1     | 2010-06-15  | the msg  |
|      2     | 2010-06-16  | the msg  |
|      3     | 2010-06-14  | the msg  |
+------------+-------------+----------|
```

I want to select the single most recent message for each sender.

This seems like a GROUP BY sender_id and ORDER BY created_at but I'm having trouble getting the most recent message selected.

I'm using postgres so need an aggregate function on the created_at field in the SELECT statement if I want to order by that field so I was looking at doing something like this as an initial test

```
SELECT messages.sender_id, MAX(messages.created_at) as the_date 
FROM messages 
GROUP BY sender_id 
ORDER BY the_date DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

This seems to work but when I want to select 'message' as well I have no idea what aggregate function to use on it. I basically just want the message that corresponds to the MAX created_at.

Is there some way of getting at this or am I approaching it the wrong way?

Comment: What version are you on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ON (sender_id) *
        FROM    messages 
        ORDER BY
                sender_id, created_at DESC 
        ) q
ORDER BY
        created_at DESC
LIMIT 5
```

or this:

```
SELECT  (mi).*
FROM    (
        SELECT  (
                SELECT  mi
                FROM    messages mi
                WHERE   mi.sender_id = m.sender_id
                ORDER BY
                        created_at DESC
                LIMIT 1
                ) AS mi
        FROM    messages m
        GROUP BY
                sender_id
        ) q
ORDER BY
        (mi).created_at  DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Create an index on `(sender_id, created_at)` for this to work fast.

You may find this article interesting:

- [**PostgreSQL: Selecting records holding group-wise maximum**](http://explainextended.com/2009/11/26/postgresql-selecting-records-holding-group-wise-maximum/)

Comment: This one gives a different result, the sort order is different.

Comment: @Frank:  you can use this a as sub query and reorder the results with your upper query.

Comment: @Frank: the original question did not mention the order on `sender_id`, but here is the query with the corrected order.

Comment: In relation to the article, I can't use any of the 8.4 methods like windows functions as I'm on 8.3. The 2nd query you gave there gives an error (syntax error at or near "mi"). I need the order to be by date so can't use the DISTINCT ON idea there either.

Comment: @johnnymire: see the post update. As for the second query, which line does it give the error on?

Comment: PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "mi"
LINE 1: ...id = m.sender_id ORDER BY the_date DESC LIMIT 1 ) mi FROM ..

Comment: Great that's done it, thanks! I'll experiment with the indexes to try speed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated sub query:

```
select * from messages m1 
where m1.created_at = (
    select max(m2.create_at) 
    from messages m2 
    where m1.sender_id = m2.sender_id
);
```

The sub query is reevaluated for each row processed by the upper query.

Answer (score 0):

Use distinct on:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (sender_id) 
           sender_id,created_at,message
      FROM messages
  ORDER BY sender_id,created_at DESC
```